# How to resolve this error while pushing my code to github private repositories using NetBeans?

Tags: java, git, netbeans, github

How to resolve this error and get my git push done as quick as possible? I am over and over getting this dialog and my push is not getting done yet.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

[image]

**Follow up:** (fixed it)

```
$ /usr/local/netbeans-dev-201112080600/bin/netbeans -J-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Allocate more RAM](http://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/) to Netbeans.